# Can someone explain how the time complexity for this is O(n^2)?

Tags: c

```
int isprime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if(!(i%n))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
void main()
{
    int numprimes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < 25001; i++)
        numprimes += isprime(i);
    printf("%d\n", numprimes);
}
```

I just recently learned about time complexity but what I see here is that we are doing n/2 operations 25000 times. Am I wrong? How exactly is this N^2?

Comment: It's (probably) assumed here that 25000 is the value of N. To be clearer this should have been an input.

Comment: Make a table where you calculate how many operations you do for different values of *N* (currently *N* = 25000). Observe how the result is proportional to *N* ^2.

Comment: @mch The loops you wrote are O(N^2), not O(N*logN). 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N(N+1)/2 = O(N^2).

Comment: Ohh okay yeah I can instantly see how it's N^2 if 25000 is N sorry for the stupid question guys thanks

Comment: @mch It's not a matter of opinion. It's about facts. And you're wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your outer loop runs from 2 to 25000, and for each number you run an inner loop that goes from 2 to floor(n/2).

It is obvious that if we let the outer and inner loop start at 1, we don't add much overhead.

Let's put the bits together.
In the first iteration (n = 1), the inner loop won't even start (you should, by the way, put the `return 1` outside of the for-loop).
The next iteration will add n/2 steps from the inner loop (if we assume that all numbers are prime).

So we end up with \sum_{i=1}^{N} i/2 = 1/2 * \sum_{i=1}^{N} i = 1/2 * (N(N+1)/2) = 1/4 N^2 + small terms, which proves that the complexity will be O(N^2)